# How to write these methods to change the x and y position in a constructible function?

Tags: javascript

I am currently stuck and not sure how to change the position of the character 20 pixels to the right and 20 pixels to the left. I have been able to create the characters and display their information. This was the code I got back when I asked for help and has still left me confused. This is the part that I am trying to do, complete the method to change the x position and complete the method to change the y position.

> ### Your task
>
> You are tasked with building the characters for a browser based game based on skeleton JavaScript code provided.
>
> The game will have 3 characters each based on objects in the JavaScript code. Each character has the following traits:
>
> - A name
> - Start position on the screen (which is comprised of two coordinates [x and y]. These coordinates show position in pixels across the x axis and down the y axis. For example (150, 230) would be 150 pixels across the screen from the left side along the x axis and 230 pixels down the screen from the top along the y axis. (See the image below.)
>
>   Hint: use separate variables for x position and y position
> - The ability to move 20 pixels at a time (for x this move is left or right and for y this move is up or down) [this looks like a method]. E.g. if the character is at (100, 30) a left move of 20 pixels puts the character at (80, 30).
>
> For x a left move is -20 and a right move is +20 pixels
>
> For y an up move is -20 and a down move is +20 pixels

```js
var Character = function(name, xPos, yPos) {
  this.name = name;
  this.xPos = xPos;
  this.yPos = yPos;

  // the changedXPos and changedYPos functions are part of the prototype itself
  // therefore they should be inside the prototype's outer braces { }
  this.changedXPos = function(value) {
    this.xPos = xPos + value;
    // change the x position here
    value = 20;
  }
  console.log(value);
  this.changedYPos = function(value) {
    // complete this similar to what we've done in the changedXPos function
  }
  this.details = function() {
    return "The person's name is: " + this.name + " and their xPos is: " + this.xPos + "and their yPos is: " + this.yPos
  };
  Character.prototype.toString = function toString() {
    var info = "Name: " + this.name + " xPos is " + this.xPos + " and yPos is " + this.yPos;
    return info;
  };
} // end of prototype

// create the 3 character objects here
// output the name and currect position of each character

var john = new Character("John", 10, 30);

console.log(john.toString(john));

var joe = new Character("Joe", 40, 20);

console.log(joe.toString(joe));

var doe = new Character("Doe", 50, 10);

console.log(doe.toString(doe));

// change the position of each character
// output the new position of each character

// now call the changedXPos and changedYPos functions
john.changedXPos(20);
john.changedYPos(50);
// print the new position to the console
console.log("new position for john: " + john.toString(john));
```

Comment: what do you mean by change position to the right and the left? can you explain more, anyway check this link if this is what you want https://js.do/code/changeposition I will post it as an answer

Comment: What isn’t working with the way you implemented `changedXPos`? What do you think is the purpose of `value = 20;`? Where do you expect `console.log(value);` to get `value` from? The comments in the code aren’t useful as they don’t clarify anything. What are the (badly named) methods `changedXPos` and `changedYPos` supposed to do?

Comment: I have added the information from the assessment I was given and what they are asking me to do

Comment: @Bec This sounds more like the implementation should include a `moveLeft`, a `moveRight`, a `moveUp`, and a `moveDown` method which just decrease or increase `this.x` or `this.y` by `20`.

Comment: I think the assignment wanted him to just change the value of x and y property, of the created object I totally agree with you the question in not the best, 
@Bec did you check the link I sent above, https://js.do/code/changeposition

Comment: @MostafaHassan yes I did thank you

Comment: So did this solve your problem to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you just need to delete unreferenced variable console.log(value) and update the property x and y in there setters

```
<script>

var Character = function(name, xPos, yPos) {
  this.name = name;
  this.xPos = xPos;
  this.yPos = yPos;

  // the changedXPos and changedYPos functions are part of the prototype itself
  // therefore they should be inside the prototype's outer braces { }
  this.changedXPos = function(value) {
    this.xPos = value;
  }
  
  this.changedYPos = function(value) {
    this.yPos = value;
  }
  this.details = function() {
    return "The person's name is: " + this.name + " and their xPos is: " + this.xPos + "and their yPos is: " + this.yPos
  };
  Character.prototype.toString = function toString() {
    var info = "Name: " + this.name + " xPos is " + this.xPos + " and yPos is " + this.yPos;
    return info;
  };
} // end of prototype

// create the 3 character objects here
// output the name and currect position of each character

var john = new Character("John", 10, 30);

console.log(john.toString(john));

var joe = new Character("Joe", 40, 20);

console.log(joe.toString(joe));

var doe = new Character("Doe", 50, 10);

console.log(doe.toString(doe));

// change the position of each character
// output the new position of each character

// now call the changedXPos and changedYPos functions
john.changedXPos(20);
john.changedYPos(50);
// print the new position to the console
console.log("new position for john: " + john.toString(john));
document.write("new position for john: " + john.toString(john));
</script>
```